# objective-c: how to assign string to NSMutableData?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, nsdata

I am to send data to digital meter for which I want data in NSMutableData form. I am trying to assign it data but getting errors.

```
NSMutableData *body = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithData:[NSData @"1"];
```

I want to asign string e.g. "1", "start" etc to NSMutableData.

Comment: What is the specific error you are getting`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't convert directly from an NSString to `NSMutableData`, you have to encode the string as `NSData` first. (There are several ways to go from NSData to NSMutableData, but I think `mutableCopy` is the clearest.);

**Try this:**

```
NSString *yourString  = @"Your string text";
NSData *data = [yourString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSMutableData *body = [data mutableCopy];
```

Comment: The first line is a common misunderstanding and useless code.  Just NSString *yourString  = @" your String text"; is all that is necessary.

Comment: @RaviChokshi can we get connected on FB ?

Answer (score 2):

```
NSString *str = @"ABC";    
NSMutableData* body = (NSMutableData *)[str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: Just casting a NSData to an NSMutableData is wrong even though it usually works.  body is still just a NSData.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableData* body = [[@"1" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] mutableCopy];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could convert NSString into NSData with`[@"1" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]`, the rest of your code is OK.

```
NSMutableData *body = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithData:[@"1" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```